# Project not in eclipse build path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

I have multiple versions of a maven project checked in to perforce. I want to make a change in an older version. But when I try and import the older version from perforce or from the disk, it does not compile in eclipse.

Right clicking on the orject does not give me 'build path' options.  How do I make sure the project is in its classpath?

I checked to see the contents of the folder and it has the .project and .settings files

Comment: right click ->proprieties -> build path ?

Comment: no actions available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by running mvn eclipse:eclipse from command line

Answer (score 1):

I've had that happen to me before. For no reason, the Build Path option disappears from the first right click menu.

Not to worry, just right click and select Properties, then choose Java Build Path from the list on the left.